# tsconfig type-import problems in VisualStudio TypeScript file for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2019, typescript-typings, tsconfig

For a mocha test runner, i want to define my own fetch-function. 
It should take the base-url from the dom-document.

So I import JSDOM and node-fetch, and write a function dom_fetch that gets the dom-location-url, and combines the URL, and does the fetch-request with node-fetch.

I got the fundamental problem that the NodeJS typescript-definitions are not part of the default-VisualStudio-TypeScript SDK (Visual Studio 2019, not Visual Studio Code).

So i had to figure out how to modify my dev-environment to include the NodeJS d.ts files.

so I did:

```
cd /d "D:\\username\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\"
git clone https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
```

And changed my tsconfig.json as follows:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,

  "compilerOptions": {

    // "target": "ES5", //"target": "es5",
    // "target": "ES2015",
    // "target": "ES2019",
    "target": "ES2018", // Set the target ECMAScript version (adjust as needed)

    //"module": "amd", // define, export, like playground
    // "module": "commonjs", // require
    // "module": "ES2015", // just like typescript
    // "module": "system", // System.register
    // "module": "umd", // factory, require, exports
    // "module": "esnext", // like typescript
    // "module": "none", // Object.defineProperty, require
    "module": "commonjs", // Use CommonJS module system for Node.js
    "lib": [ "ES2018" ], // Include the Node.js ES2018 features


    "types": [ "node", "node-fetch", "jsdom" ],
    // npm install --save-dev @types/node 
    "typeRoots": [ "D:\\username\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\DefinitelyTyped\\types" ],

    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",


    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "../../wwwroot/Checklist2/ts/testing",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "allowUnreachableCode": true
    //,"alwaysStrict ": true,
  },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "wwwroot"
    ],

    "include": [
      "**/*"
    ]

  }
```

This could be improved by using relative paths, but anyway.

Then I tried to implement my dom_fetch function.
It works when it's being declared as follows:

```
/// <reference types="node-fetch" />
/// <reference types="jsdom" />

"use strict";



// TS2304: Cannot find name 'global' #70
// You probably need to do npm install @types/node because global comes from node.
// This is not a ts-proto issue but just a TypeScript/node issue, so please use stackoverflow / etc.to resolve from here on out.
// https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/node

// https://khalilstemmler.com/blogs/typescript/node-starter-project/
// declare var global: any;
// const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom'); 
// const fetch = require('node-fetch'); 
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";
import fetch, { RequestInfo, RequestInit } from "../../../../DefinitelyTyped/types/node-fetch";


const dom = new JSDOM('<html><body></body></html>', {
    url: 'https://example.com/foo/bar/', // Set the base URL here
});

// global.window = dom.window;
(<any>global).window = dom.window;
// global.document = dom.window.document;
(<any>global).document = dom.window.document;


// Get the base URL from global.window.location.origin
async function dom_fetch(relativePath: RequestInfo, options?: RequestInit)
{
    // Check if the provided relativePath is already a full URL
    const isFullUrl = /^https?:\/\//i.test(relativePath.toString());
    const baseUrl = (<any>global).window?.location?.origin || '';
    // Construct the absolute URL based on the base URL or use the full URL

    const url = isFullUrl ? relativePath : new URL(relativePath.toString(), this.baseUrl);

    // Make the fetch request
    const response = await fetch(url.toString(), options);

    // You can handle the response here or return it to the caller
    return response;
}


// usage: 
// global.window.fetch = dom_fetch;
(<any>global).window.fetch = dom_fetch;

// global.fetch = dom_fetch
(<any>global).fetch = dom_fetch;
```

**What I would like to know, why those differences in import between JSDOM anf fetch ?** 
I understand `"../../../../DefinitelyTyped/types/node-fetch"` is the realtive path from the current typescript file. 
But why does it work without that relative path for jsdom, but not for fetch ?

**Also, why does node-type include the definition of global, but URL is not included ?** 
I have to import URL manually, whereas in NodeJS, URL is clearly included...

url.d.ts is also part of the nodejs type:

```
D:\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\DefinitelyTyped\types\node\url.d.ts
```